# UTFDataFormatException and ClassNotFoundException when adding an image to Liferay portlet

Tags: java, image, jsp, liferay, portlet

I use Liferay 5.2.3 on Tomcat 5.5. I added the tag

```
<img alt="G.png" src="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/images/G.png">
```

to one of the JSPs that I dispatch my portlet to, and I received:

```
ERROR [http-8080-Processor22] (StandardWrapperValve.java:253) Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.io.UTFDataFormatException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
        at org.apache.jasper.xmlparser.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(UTF8Reader.java:621)
        at org.apache.jasper.xmlparser.UTF8Reader.read(UTF8Reader.java:492)
        at org.apache.jasper.xmlparser.XMLEncodingDetector.load(XMLEncodingDetector.java:1000)
        at org.apache.jasper.xmlparser.XMLEncodingDetector.skipString(XMLEncodingDetector.java:951)
        at org.apache.jasper.xmlparser.XMLEncodingDetector.scanXMLDecl(XMLEncodingDetector.java:1209)
        at org.apache.jasper.xmlparser.XMLEncodingDetector.getEncoding(XMLEncodingDetector.java:121)
        at org.apache.jasper.xmlparser.XMLEncodingDetector.getEncoding(XMLEncodingDetector.java:109)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.determineSyntaxAndEncoding(ParserController.java:305)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:170)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:101)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:156)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:296)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:277)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:265)
        at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:564)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:302)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:154)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.header.HeaderFilter.processFilter(HeaderFilter.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:91)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(PortalClassLoaderFilter.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:875)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

ERROR [http-8080-Processor20] (StandardWrapperValve.java:253) Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.images.G_png
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:131)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
        at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(JspCompilationContext.java:597)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:137)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:314)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:154)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.header.HeaderFilter.processFilter(HeaderFilter.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:91)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(PortalClassLoaderFilter.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:875)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Some images are loaded well and some are not.

What could be going wrong?

Comment: Just to precise: G.png exists in images subfolder of portlet war.

Answer (score 0):

We reference images in our jsp by creating a tag

using the following syntax

```
<%@ tag isELIgnored="false" body-content="empty" %>${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/
```

Stored in a file called imagesPath in /WEB-INF/tags/html
then use that in the jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="html" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/html" %>




<img src="<html:imagesPath />intro.jpg"  alt="Introduction"/>
```

I am guessing the important bit of this that you are missing is the pageContext ?

Comment: Thanks, but well... it doesn't work for me. It's just another way of rendering img tag, but error occurs, when browser requests for image. In both cases img tag is rendered properly (my portlet context path is /DataCenter): <img src="/DataCenter/images/G.png">.